# How to add textbox and buttons in BlogSpot post?

Tags: button, uibutton, user-input, blogspot

Currently, I can only add static posts to my blog. I can not use it for dynamic purposes like I can do it sites. I want to add text boxes and buttons depending on user input , I want to show dynamic content on my blog.

So it this possible?
I searched on the net but can only find that Blogspot does not allows text boxes and buttons to be added.
Please post some sample code for it.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blogspot posts doesn't allow to insert "input" tag in its posts directly by HTML Editor of posts. To do so you can follow the following steps

1. Goto the Templete from Admin portal of your blog
2. click on edit html & add JQuery.js (preferably which is hosted on google /JQueryUI.
3. in your post add a div in which you will add your input contents.
4. Now again in your templete html editor, write JQuery to handle event and adding the controls

for demo code you  can view this article
[Insert input elements in blogspot's post](http://akashsoni7.blogspot.in/2012/12/blogspot-hacking-how-to-insert-input.html)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I saw the sample code. It works for the button. Can you please add some sample code for text box too? I am new to blogspot, javascript and HTML. Thanks.

Comment: The javascript code written there contains a DOM method to create button i.e. document.createElement("button"). that thing creates button there. Now to create text box use following steps 

var textbox = document.createElement("input"); 
textbox.setAttribute("type", "text");

keep remaining code same
for adding the textbox in div write

element.appendChild(textbox)